# How would I go about creating my own SDK to allow users to develop their own addon mods?

Tags: scripting

I am looking into developing a game, but I am very interested in the more abstract concepts such as modding. I would like to know, or get linked to information detailing the prerequisites, architecture and general idea behind, how I would develop an add-on mod support with a language such as C++ or C# specifically, although any language will be fine.

The mod would work alike to Minecraft, it adds onto the current game giving more content, but doesn't change any base code.

I'd love some detailed answers and I am more than happy to clarify anything that I didn't explain well or if I didn't provide enough information.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. There are lots of ways to do this and it depends on how you want things to work. Can you give more details about the technical implementation you're looking for? This is a fairly high level question about the same topic: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63804/how-to-attract-modders-to-your-game

Comment: You will probably want to use a scripting language such as Lua (Factorio is a good example). Mods created in compiled languages would need to be loaded via libraries and could contain and run arbitrary code.  Minecraft modding (with Forge) does indeed require modifying the base code in order for Forge to inject its classes/API into the game and have them loaded and run.

Comment: ok, well could you provide me with a couple of links on how to interface with libraries in such a way, preferably c++ or C#. I will have a look, but this seems like something that will help.